# PyQt file copy progress bar

Tags: pyqt

I am trying to get a QProgressBar to show the progress of a file copy in PyQt. I've looked about and I've got as far as running the actual copy in a thread using QFile. I just can't get the bar to update though.

Here's some code:

```
class ProgressDialog(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent, source, destination):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.source = source
        self.destination = destination

        self.add_diag = progress_diag.Ui_Dialog()
        self.add_diag.setupUi(self)

        self.add_diag.infoLabel.setText("Copying: %s" % (self.source))
        self.sourcefile = QtCore.QFile(self.source)

        self.add_diag.progressBar.setMinimum(0)
        self.add_diag.progressBar.setMaximum(self.sourcefile.size()/1024)

        self.written = 0

        self.show()
        self.copy()

    def copy(self):

        copy_thread = CopyThread(self, self.sourcefile, self.destination)
        self.connect(copy_thread.destination_file, QtCore.SIGNAL("bytesWritten(qint64)"), self.update_progress)
        copy_thread.procDone.connect(self.finished_copy)
        copy_thread.start()

    def update_progress(self, progress):
        print "Working", progress
        self.written += progress
        self.add_diag.progressBar.setValue(written/1024)

    def finished_copy(self, state):
        self.close()

class CopyThread(QtCore.QThread):

    procDone = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self, parent, source, destination):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.source = source
        self.destination_file = QtCore.QFile(destination)

    def run(self):
        self.source.copy(self.destination_file.fileName())
        self.procDone.emit(True)
```

update_progess never gets called so the signal obviously isn't being emitted but I'm not sure why.

I've searched high and low on this but haven't found a good PyQt solution for this so any help would be great.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is in CopyThread... Which is not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here's what I came up with which works but obviously slows down the file copy performance.

```
class ProgressDialog(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent, source, destination):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.source = source
        self.destination = destination
        self.add_diag = progress_diag.Ui_Dialog()
        self.add_diag.setupUi(self)

        self.add_diag.infoLabel.setText("Copying: %s" % (self.source))

        self.add_diag.progressBar.setMinimum(0)
        self.add_diag.progressBar.setMaximum(100)
        self.add_diag.progressBar.setValue(0)

        self.show()
        self.copy()

    def copy(self):

        copy_thread = CopyThread(self, self.source, self.destination)
        copy_thread.procPartDone.connect(self.update_progress)
        copy_thread.procDone.connect(self.finished_copy)
        copy_thread.start()

    def update_progress(self, progress):
        self.add_diag.progressBar.setValue(progress)

    def finished_copy(self, state):
        self.close()

class CopyThread(QtCore.QThread):

    procDone = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)
    procPartDone = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent, source, destination):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.source = source
        self.destination = destination

    def run(self):
        self.copy()
        self.procDone.emit(True)

    def copy(self):
        source_size = os.stat(self.source).st_size
        copied = 0
        source = open(self.source, "rb")
        target = open(self.destination, "wb")

        while True:
            chunk = source.read(1024)
            if not chunk:
                break
            target.write(chunk)
            copied += len(chunk)
            self.procPartDone.emit(copied * 100 / source_size)

        source.close()
        target.close()
```

Comment: Although slow, this is very useful - A file of about 3GB takes about 15 seconds with an ordinary windows copy - my program moves it and updates the progressbar and finishes in about 28. Do you know how it might be sped up?

Answer (score 0):

QFile does not emit bytesWritten:

> Unlike other QIODevice
>   implementations, such as QTcpSocket,
>   QFile does not emit the
>   aboutToClose(), bytesWritten(), or
>   readyRead() signals. This
>   implementation detail means that QFile
>   is not suitable for reading and
>   writing certain types of files, such
>   as device files on Unix platforms.

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfile.html

You will have to implement your own loop and emit the progress yourself.